# How do I get rid of the Notificationexec error in OS X Lion?

Tags: macos, powerpc

I made the mistake of attempting to run the Maxtor Hard Drive Manager Installer on OS X Lion. It doesn't run because it is a PowerPC app. I uninstalled it but I still get a popup alert every 10 seconds which makes the Mac impossible to use. I looked up forums but nothing helped. Best suggestion was to go to the Library folder and remove the relevant files under Driver Support folder. Unfortunately I don't have such a folder. I removed a dmg file with Maxtor name but it still didn't help.

I would truly appreciate any on this matter as it seems that I am stuck.

Thanks.

Comment: OK. Here is the solution I found, which is terrible but it works. Basically, I went to the Finder, opened the Search Criteria and searched for anything with named Maxtor and Seagate. After deleting several files, one of which had the word notification in it, I don't see the popup anymore. Most other solutions on Apple support site refer to removing files from Library -> Driver Support but I had no such folder. So if no other solution works for you, I suggest that you go to the finder and delete everything as I described above.

Comment: Have you tried searching the app with [AppCleaner](http://www.freemacsoft.net/)?

Comment: No. But the method I explained above worked.

Comment: If it did work, you probably could add it as an answer by now :-)

Comment: Good point. :-)

Answer (score 4):

OK. Here is the solution I found, which is terrible but it works. Basically, I went to the Finder, opened the Search Criteria and searched for anything with named Maxtor and Seagate. After deleting several files, one of which had the word notification in it, I don't see the popup anymore. Most other solutions on Apple support site refer to removing files from Library -> Driver Support but I had no such folder. So if no other solution works for you, I suggest that you go to the finder and delete everything as I described above.

Comment: Ok I did all that was suggested... It leave files everywhere.... I finnaly found the driver support file.....
1. Go to finder... Top of screen
2. Hit go
3. Hit computer
4. Hit Macintosh HD
5. Hit driver support Deleat the files.